# How to pass a "refresh" callback via useContext that uses a hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
const UserContext = useContext({
    user: null,
    fetch: null,
});

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    
    const useFetchUser = () => {
        return useSWR('/api/self', getSelf);
    };
    
    const { data } = useFetchUser();
    
    const context = {
        user: data,
        fetch: useFetchUser
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

const useUser = () => {
    return useContext(UserContext);
}

const SomeComponent = () => {
    const { user, fetch } = useUser();
    
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            <button onClick={() => fetch()} >Fetch User</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to pass the `useFetchUser` as a callback through the context, so if you were to click it, it would re-fetch the user and update the `user` field for the entire context.

This right now does not work and throws hooks error. How can I do this? I know I can basically do `await getSelf()` and use my own `useState` to manage the data, fetching, error, etc, but I want to use `useSWR` (or more generally, pass a hook as a callback).

Thanks!